# User Profile Synchronisation Service Provision Problem

Tags: user-profile-service

I'm having exactly the same problem as stated here: https://serverfault.com/questions/148924/sharepoint-2010-user-profile-synchronization.

I checked the page at harbar.net but I don't know what account was used to create the farm, and I don't want to re-isntall everything from start.

Is there any other method to solve this?

Edit: I will edit this post to include the original problem as soon as I got some time.

Comment: A couple of points: please fix question so it contains **your** problem, not just a link to someone elses problem. That link could be dead in the future (and the question even contains links to other pages)... The reason you cannot tag with SKU is that this tag has been revoked from highest place. See discussion on meta: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no specific need that i know of to know what user installed the farm. You do need to know the farm account, but that will already be present when you try to start the sync service.

Also this sync service **needs to be local admin** when service is started (this permission should be revoked after service has started). This is the no. 1 reason for the "stuck on starting" problem. Also i recommend a reboot before starting the service (or a restart of all services running under the farm account) to make this permission take effect.

Also an IISRESET must be run before you can successfully enter the User Profile Service in Central Administration.

As Omar said on Stack Overflow follow Spence's guide **to the letter** -no shortcuts- and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using a SQL Server named instance (eg SERVER\SHAREPOINT), and that you didn't use the SQL Server FQDN (eg server.domain.name\SHAREPOINT) when installing SharePoint. UPS (or more precisely Forefront Identity Manager, FIM) can't handle either.